# How to prevent caller from continuing after redirect_to in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I defined a before filter in my controller:

```
before_filter :find,  :only => [:caller]
```

and I want to catch exceptions in "find" method :

```
def find 
   begin
     ...
   rescue Exception
     redirect_to somewhere
   end
 end
```

but how can I prevent the "caller" method from continuing executing ?

Answer (score 2):

If a `before_filter` renders or redirects, the execution stops automatically.

Learn more: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters

For `ActiveRecord` callbacks like `before_validation`, use `return false` to stop the record from being saved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `return` after the redirect in the rescue?

```
    redirect_to ...
    return # <<
  end
end
```

Comment: I normally don't like the use of 'and' (I prefer to use && to avoid issues with precedence), but I find it useful to use it with a redirect:

redirect_to root_url and return

It avoids the double render/redirect errors and makes sense to others reading your code.